# AuthorizeHttpRequest in Springboot Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I want the root only to be publicly accessible, this is how I'm doing it, but it doesn't seem to work as every URL including the root requires me to pass by the login interface

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http)throws Exception{
         http.authorizeHttpRequests()
         .requestMatchers("/")
         .permitAll()
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and().httpBasic();
     return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: What URL do you enter in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

.requestMatchers("/**") should fix it.

More details:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
```

Add the EnableMethodSecurity another to allow some PreAuths on API pathing via your controllers, I like to batch do this via Interfaces as Spring Boot now allows it.

```
@PostMapping("/URL")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE')")
public ResponseEntity<T> method(
```

The PreAuthorize annotation is basically short way of doing hasRole in your security filter chain.

Comment: Didn't work, this makes every URL publicly accessible recursively.

Comment: Enable the method security in your security configuration and start adding required authorities to other URLs in your API pathing on Controllers then - main comment updated for clarity.